# Edge Ngram splits tokens with periods

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm using django-haystack 1.2.5 with solr as my backend

I have some autocomplete fields which use the EdgeNgramField field.

I cannot get results for the following string: "8.75%"

I took a look at my autogenerated schema.xml file and noticed that the EdgeNgram uses the WordDelimiterFilterFactory. According to Solr's documentation, this filter does a "split on intra-word delimiters (all non alpha-numeric characters)."

What adjustments can I make to get results for a string with a period in the middle?

I don't want to take out the filter, because it may be useful for other things such as abbreviations (eg A.C.M.E.) Perhaps there's some way I could specify a regexp so it won't split a numerical decimal?

**EDIT
here is my TextField fieldset:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Can you post the analyzer chains for `text` fieldType from the auto-generated schema.xml? i.e. everything in `<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" ... </fieldType>`

Comment: hey arun, see my edit for the requested post... Im thinking of putting preserveOriginal="1" in the wordDelimitedFactory, but should that be in the EdgeNgramFieldset and not the TextField fieldset?

Comment: tried it in both, and it still doesnt work

Comment: According to the definition of `text` in your schema, you should have gotten a match without any changes. Is the field type you are searching on `text` or something else? You can try analysis on your solr instance at http://localhost:8983/solr/CORE/admin/analysis.jsp to see what is getting matched.